# Execute command when command-line pipe result is not null or not empty

Tags: bash, command-line

For example:

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/lambda' |\
  jq -r '.name'
```

return value of "**name**" json attribute. If this attribute is empty or not exist command return **null** or '':

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/lambda' |\
 jq -r '.blabla'
```

I need to run command like `python main.py` when command above return not null or not empty value. Like:

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/lambda' |\
 jq -r '.name' | ..... python main.py
```

I plan to setup it using cron and parse external json like flag to run local script..

Comment: Return values in bash are stored in $? If that helps.

Comment: Your description is not quite clear. Do you mean you need to run the Python command whenever the `jq` command issues a non-empty string? In this case, you could try `if [ -n "$(curl ... | jq ...)" ]; then python ...; fi`. The `-n` means "non-zero length" and can be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the command is successful, regardless of the output, you'll have to save it in a variable and pass it to your script if it isn't empty. It looks like you only get empty when you request data for a known field that has no value (e.g. `.gravatar_id`) and you get `null` if you pass an unknown field (e.g. `.blabla`). To accommodate both, you can do:

```
var=$(curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/lambda' | jq -r '.name')
[ "$var" != "null" -a -n "$var" ] && printf '%s\n' "$var" | python main.py
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[ -n "$var" ] && [ "$var" != "null" ]`?

Comment: @freddy no, because it is never empty when jq is being redirected to a variable. I tested, and as far as I can tell it's always "null". You only see empty (and it isn't actually empty) when you print to standard output.

Comment: It's actually more about `!=` vs. `-ne`. I get an empty variable with `var=$(echo | jq -r '.name')`, but that might be caused by my jq version (1.5+dfsg-2+b1, Debian buster).

Comment: The output is "null" when `jq` gets a valid object/array, but the object doesn't have the searched-for identifier. It is empty when `jq` gets an empty input. However, noting that `null` may be a valid value for `.name`, it's probably better to change the `jq` script into `if (.name == null) then "" else .name end` and then check whether the output is empty.

Comment: @Freddy eek! Of course that should be `!=`, thanks. The `-ne` was a copy/paste error from a previous trial I'd made.

Comment: @terdon `[ -z $(curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/lambda' | jq -r '.gravatar_id') ] && echo foo` = `foo`. Doesn't it mean that the result of the command *is* empty?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes indeed, thanks! Apparently you get empty if it is a known field with no value and `null` when it is an unknown field. Answer edited.